# Least Expensive Android Phone for TTS SW Development?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I know many developers ask about the *best* Android phone for development, but my question is almost opposite: What is the *least expensive* Android phone that I can get away with TTS (text-to-speech) and ASR (automated-speech-recognition) software development?

To further clarify my question:

1. Do **all** Android phones support
   TTS *and* ASR?
2. Do **all** Android OS versions
   support TTS *and* ASR?
3. If the answer to either of the above
   is 'No', then which brand/model will
   provide me with TTS *and* ASR functionality
   while minimizing out-of-pocket
   expense?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do all Android phones support TTS and ASR?

They should, subject to:

> Do all Android OS versions support TTS and ASR?

ASR came in Android 1.5. TTS was added in Android 1.6.

Be careful when dealing with non-phones, though, as they may not have a microphone.